# How to reset a multiple form in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Need to reset a multiple form's fields.
I can able to reset a form one by one by using below codes:

```
$scope.form1.$setPristine();
$scope.form2.$setPristine();
$scope.form3.$setPristine();
```

Is there any way to reset all the forms instantly without using loops?

Comment: Set `$scope.form1 = {};`

Comment: @Sajal: I need to reset all the three forms.

Comment: Individually, set the forms `= {}`

Answer (score 0):

I would look into ng-form.

Having form1, form2, and form3 as nested forms of a parent form (formParent), calling $scope.formParent.$setPristine() causes it to cascade to all nested forms.

HTML:

```
<form name='formParent' novalidate>
  <ng-form name='form1'>
    <input name='input1' />
  </ng-form>
  <ng-form name='form2'>
    <input name='input2' />
  </ng-form>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MyController',['$scope',function($scope) {

  activate();

  function activate(){
     $scope.formParent.$setPristine()
  }

}]);
```

Comment: This is not a good structure to maintain a "form inside form".

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm The angular team would disagree when it comes to validation.